# How to put a Sprite in ThreeJS?

Tags: three.js

Hi I'm new to ThreeJS and finding the tutorials are not helping.  I've followed the tutorials, however I still can not see my sprites when I load them.  What am I doing wrong?

```
    // ========================== THE SPRITE =============================== // 

    var spriteMap = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( "assets/images/logoBBG2.png" );
    var spriteMaterial = new THREE.SpriteMaterial( { map: spriteMap, color: 0xffffff } );   
    var sprite = new THREE.Sprite( spriteMaterial );
    sprite.center.set(0,1); 
    sprite.position.set(0,0,-40);   
    sprite.scale.set(64,64,1.0); 
    scene.add(sprite);
```

Comment: Where and how do you set your animation loop? For example, in the end after `scene.add(sprite)`: `renderer.setAnimationLoop( () => { renderer.render(scene, camera) } );`

Comment: At minimum, you will need to call renderer.render(scene,camera) at least once to get a frame rendered.

Comment: Yes I have all that, I just wanted to focus on the sprite code.  The scene renders, but there is no sprite showing....

Comment: it's better to provide a live working example (code snippet, jsfiddle, codepen).